# Libgdx coordinate system

Tags: java, libgdx

I just started with libgdx and I'm still figuring out how the coordinate system work.The code below would draw the image at [0,0] without the Orthographic camera

What I can't understand is why the code doesn't draw the image when I uncomment the camera and viewport. I thought the camera is at point [0,0] by default. But I'm not sure why I can't see the image.

[Edit]
Reading the question I posted this morning, I guess what I want to ask is how camera and viewport affect the coorindates that is passed to the SpriteBatch.

**Working code**

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport;

public class SpriteBatchSample extends GdxSample {
    private static final Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = new Color(0.39f, 0.58f, 0.92f, 1.0f);
    private static final float WORLD_TO_SCREEN = 1f;
    private static final float SCENE_WIDTH = 100f;
    private static final float SCENE_HEIGHT = 100f;

    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Viewport viewport;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Texture cavemanTexture;
    private Texture sbTexture;
    private Color oldColor;

    @Override
    public void create() {      
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        viewport = new FitViewport(SCENE_WIDTH, SCENE_HEIGHT, camera);
        //Gdx.app.log("SpriteBatch",    camera.position.toString());
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        oldColor = new Color();
        camera.position.set(100/2f, 100/2f,0);
        cavemanTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/sb.png"));
        cavemanTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Nearest, TextureFilter.Nearest);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        cavemanTexture.dispose();
        sbTexture.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {      
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(BACKGROUND_COLOR.r,
                BACKGROUND_COLOR.g,
                BACKGROUND_COLOR.b,
                BACKGROUND_COLOR.a);

        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        //batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        batch.begin();

        int width = cavemanTexture.getWidth();
        int height = cavemanTexture.getHeight();
        float originX = width * 0.5f;
        float originY = height * 0.5f;
        Gdx.app.log("SpriteBatchSample", "width " + width + "\n"
            + "height: " + height + "\n"
            + "originX" + originX + "\n"
        );

        // Draw
        batch.draw(cavemanTexture,
                0, 0,                       // x, y
                originX, originY,                           // originX, originY
                cavemanTexture.getWidth(), cavemanTexture.getHeight(),// width, height
                WORLD_TO_SCREEN, WORLD_TO_SCREEN,           // scaleX, scaleY
                0.0f,                                       // rotation
                0, 0,                                       // srcX, srcY
                cavemanTexture.getWidth(),cavemanTexture.getHeight(),   // srcWidth, srcHeight
                false, false);                              // flipX, flipY



        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        //viewport.update(width, height, false);
    }
}
```

***Not Working***

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport;

public class SpriteBatchSample extends GdxSample {
    private static final Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = new Color(0.39f, 0.58f, 0.92f, 1.0f);
    private static final float WORLD_TO_SCREEN = 1f;
    private static final float SCENE_WIDTH = 100f;
    private static final float SCENE_HEIGHT = 100f;

    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Viewport viewport;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Texture cavemanTexture;
    private Texture sbTexture;
    private Color oldColor;

    @Override
    public void create() {      
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        viewport = new FitViewport(SCENE_WIDTH, SCENE_HEIGHT, camera);
        //Gdx.app.log("SpriteBatch",    camera.position.toString());
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        oldColor = new Color();
        camera.position.set(100/2f, 100/2f,0);
        cavemanTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/sb.png"));
        cavemanTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Nearest, TextureFilter.Nearest);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        cavemanTexture.dispose();
        sbTexture.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {      
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(BACKGROUND_COLOR.r,
                BACKGROUND_COLOR.g,
                BACKGROUND_COLOR.b,
                BACKGROUND_COLOR.a);

        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        batch.begin();

        int width = cavemanTexture.getWidth();
        int height = cavemanTexture.getHeight();
        float originX = width * 0.5f;
        float originY = height * 0.5f;
        Gdx.app.log("SpriteBatchSample", "width " + width + "\n"
            + "height: " + height + "\n"
            + "originX" + originX + "\n"
        );

        // Draw
        batch.draw(cavemanTexture,
                0, 0,                       // x, y
                originX, originY,                           // originX, originY
                cavemanTexture.getWidth(), cavemanTexture.getHeight(),// width, height
                WORLD_TO_SCREEN, WORLD_TO_SCREEN,           // scaleX, scaleY
                0.0f,                                       // rotation
                0, 0,                                       // srcX, srcY
                cavemanTexture.getWidth(),cavemanTexture.getHeight(),   // srcWidth, srcHeight
                false, false);                              // flipX, flipY



        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width, height, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the point of this question? If you want to learn what happens behind the scenes then read the documentation, if not just use it as intended. You cant expect the game to resize itself automatically and you cant draw on the camera if u dont set ur batch's projectionmatrix

Comment: Sorry I'm new to game development and libgdx. I really just wanted to ask why the image isn't displayed when I use the orthographic Camera. I actually set the projection matrix when I use the camera. It's commented out on the code above because I just wanted to show the code that works without the camera. Sorry again if it's confusing

Comment: You should probably post the code that gives u the actual problem

Comment: Updated the question. Can you refer me to a documentation about how the viewport  and camera affects the  coordinates used in SpriteBatch's draw method call? I've only seen this documentation so far >> https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Projection,-viewport,-&-camera

Answer (score 0):

Because by default Camera sees your game screen from top, having it's 0,0 fixed at top left corner.

On the other hand, things you draw  in render method, have 0,0 fixed at bottom left corner.

To combine your game screen's coordinate with camera's coordinate, you use,

```
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
```

Read this article, written by libGDX creators (Mario), you would understand, how Camera actually project your images.

http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1550

Comment: Yup I'm using that mate :) After researching and watching youtube tutorials, I found out that you should think in proportions instead of exact pixel coordinates when you are using the viewport

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer to my question above. what happened was I was thinking in exact pixel coordinates. When I should have thought of world units when using viewports

yes  thecamera is centered at (0, 0) by default but the world width and height was only 100. There is a transparent space at the bottom left of my image. That is why even though it is also at (0,0) , I still can't see the image.

This video tutorial helped me a lot 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ml-XXQaN0hc
As well as this forum link
http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=19640&p=82259